# changing solr id from string to uuid

Tags: solr, indexing, uuid

I am very new to solr.

Initially the "id" in my solr schema was of type **string**.

I have 30,000 documents, but now I want to use **uuid** instead of a string.

Simply changing the id to uuid and following instructions from http://wiki.apache.org/solr/UniqueKey

It did not work because it tried to string id as uuid and it failed.

My question is how do i change my id to uuid without deleting any data ?

Any info on this will be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Hope your **id** field is be mentioned as uniqueKey in the schema.xml. That means every solr document in your Solr instance must contain the id field. When you modify the type of any field in the schema, the previously created index for those fields get messed up. Now you can't query on those field, though they are still present in your Solr instance.

What good is that if you can not query on the data, you indexed to query? So, there is no good keeping the old document in your Solr, on which you can't query. And this time you have modified the **uniqueKey** field. So, you must re-index. If you would have modified the type of other field except uniqueKey, then Atomic update or partial update would have been a solution.

Comment: Yeah. I know, it was not a smart thing to do. Do you have a smart strategy of reindexing ? I was thinking I will drop the id field and remove the uniqueKey constraint from schema.xml and start Solr and stop it. And then I will readd id filed into the schema. Will that work ?